# How do I boot my Samsung Nexus S into safe mode?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, boot

I have a Samsung Nexus S with Android 2.3.

I somehow managed to set the Zoodles application to start up with laucher. As a result, whenever I boot my phone, I see the Zoodles app and cannot close it or access any other applications.

I searched and understood that if I can boot the device in safe mode, I can remove the Zoodles app. How do I boot into safe mode?

Answer (score 2):

Try booting the phone while holding down the power button during boot. I have also read people saying that holding the menu button during boot works.

Once you are in safe mode, you will see "Safe Mode" at the bottom left of the screen.