# How to fix a force close loop on Android with phone access?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, force-close

I have a problem with my Samsung Galaxy S2 (GT-I9100) running Android 2.3.5 stock version.

I'm normal user who used the phone for basic function like making phone calls and using the Google, Facebook apps with some installed apps from the play store.

Today, 2 hours ago logsprovider initiated out of nowhere an endless loop of "force close" alerts, between them most of the running apps were closed too (including some weird z7... app).

Because of the interval (about half a second) between alerts I can goto settings -> apps -> and "clear data" in the logsprovider config.

This stops the "force close" alerts loop until the next restart of the phone. in this state I basically don't have access to the phone features and all the home screens are empty, including the phone's apps menu.

I can run any app by adding it to the home screen and then executing it, if the app has system operation like the play store that require it to install something, the app will crash and no new programs will install.

I can also connect the phone to a computer and get access to all the files (I think it's just those on storage), I might try to get an apk of an antivirus there and try to install it - hope it doesn't crash

These are desperate times... thats why I'm contacting the experts:

1. Can I fix this, this might have been caused by an app, what to do?
2. If the only solution is factory reset how do I backup the data, apps, or contact lists?

Comment: Have you tried doing a factory reset?

Answer (score 7):

## Issue solved

- Boot in recovery mode > Choose "Wipe cache partition" and reboot.

No need to Factory reset and lose all data.

## Long description

I also suddenly had my Samsung Galaxy SII (SGS2 GT-i9100) running Android 2.3.4 with a rush of continuous force close pop up windows, a lot of apps that seemed to try to connect to internet would trigger a popup force close window, many apps crashed. I hardly managed to quickly close the popups and turn off the phone, removed the battery and turned it on again but the problem persisted and got worse so in the end I got this popup again and again:

"*The application LogsProvider (process com.sec.android.provider.logsprovider) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. Force Close.*"

And really had to try hard to close all those popups quickly to switch off the phone.

I found the solution [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1305723)

Which is:

1. Turn off the phone (hold the power button if the power-off menu won't appear).
2. Boot in recovery mode (holding volume up key + home key + power button at same time).
3. Choose the fourth option "wipe cache partition" (using the volume keys to select option and then Home button to excecute).
4. Allow to reboot normally and problem solved.

Comment: wow man, cheers for this, fixed it perfectly. i've gone through countless XDA threads on the topic and was just about to factory reset my galaxy s2.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the app causing the loop, you can boot to "safe mode" and delete its cache. If it's still force-closing, do the same with its data, or even uninstall the app. For details, please refer to:

- [What is safe mode?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8258/what-is-safe-mode)
- [How do I boot my Samsung Nexus S into safe mode?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19085/how-do-i-boot-my-samsung-nexus-s-into-safe-mode)
- [How would you uninstall a rogue Home (Launcher) application?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6458/how-would-you-uninstall-a-rogue-home-launcher-application)

Answer (score 1):

Further to what Izzy answered, if you cannot isolate the problem and want to factory reset, here's what you can do:

1. Use Google account to sync contact, settings and wifi passwords etc.
2. Use [SMS backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&hl=en) app to save SMS to your SD card.
3. Save a list of apps using AppBrain app. If you need full backup including app data, root your phone and install [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup). You'll have to root it again after reset, but rooting for Galaxy S2 is easy. Here's a [guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1321582).