# The process has stopped unexpectedly - recovery

Tags: adb, factory-reset, recovery-mode, system-error, force-close

When I start my tablet `Archos 7 Home tablet` it shows this message box:

```
Sorry!
The process android.process.acore has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.
Force close
```

[image: error message]

The only possibility I have is to press the button `Force close` and then the message
appears again.

I tried to reset the tablet with pushing the needle into the `reset hole` on the back of the tablet,
[image: back hole]

but after starting the tablet the message appears again.

Now, I'm trying to solve it inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817721/wipe-data-factory-reset-through-adb) as follows but I have [stuck](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42457/problem-with-attaching-archos-device-on-ubuntu)

```
$ adb shell
$ recovery --wipe_data
```

I can only mount the tablet and browse through the directories in it. Can I destroy the files of the application that cause this error message?
How would you solve it?

Comment: You are mixing up a lot of things here. What is your real issue: a) connecting the device via `adb`, b) doing a factory reset of your device, c) solving the force-close? (Recommended reading: [How To Ask Android Questions The Smart Way](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/how-to-ask-android-questions-the-smart-way)). Please split your questions into separate posts, so they can be taken care of.

Comment: @Izzy The issue is described precisely at the beginning. Everything after words `Now, I'm trying to solve it...` is the solution that I tried and failed because I can't see the attached device.

Comment: OK, got it. A bit lengthy; you still should make the second half a separate post (and link it). I just updated the force-close tag-wiki with some generic information which might prove helpful to you; as this might take a little to be "propagated", I will copy it into an answer here. // PS: As for the `adb` stuff, do you have *USB Debugging* enabled on the device? Most devices don't show up without that.

Comment: @Izzy OK I will split it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What is a force-close?

If an application encounters an unexpected state or some other programming error, it will issue an force close. In most cases you will be presented with a form that allows you to send log files and the cause of the force close to the developer. Doing so will help the developer to fix the bug.

### First aid

- if it happens rarely, you might be able to "ignore" it. Contact the app's developer if it repeats from time to time. An extract of the [logcat](/questions/tagged/logcat) might be helpful to locate the issue.
- if it persists: a [reboot](/questions/tagged/reboot) *might* solve it
- if it still persists in a loop, preventing you accessing the device otherwise, and the app in question is one you installed yourself, you can boot into [safe-mode](/questions/tagged/safe-mode) and remove that app
- if instead it's a system app, a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) might be needed
- if your device is rooted, you might boot to [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode) and "Wipe Cache" before going to factory-reset. If this works out, you won't lose any data.

### Helpful questions/answers dealing with force-closes

- [How to fix a force close loop on Android with phone access?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/22961/16575)

Comment: My device is not rooted. It persists in a loop. My data are backed up, so I can afford lose it. I'd like to go to `safe-mode` but there is not `volume up` key on my tablet.

Comment: It persists in a loop so I can't do anything with the tablet, only to repeatedly press the "force close" button.

Comment: Your tablet has no volume buttons? I mean, no hardware buttons to adjust the volume? I never heard of such a device. I have an *Archos 70 IT* myself, and that has them. But apart from that: If it's always `android.process.acore` (which is a system process) causing the force-close, there's not much you could do from within safe-mode -- except if immediately before the problem started you installed some other app that may have caused this. In the latter case, you could of course remove that app while in *Safe Mode*.

Comment: No it has not volume buttons. [Here](http://www.archos.com/support/download/manuals/UserGuide_Archos_7_PN108446_book_V2.pdf) is the manual. It's `Archos 7 Home Tablet`

Comment: [Here](http://forum.archosfans.com/viewtopic.php?t=36896) somebody has the same problem with volume button.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a "manual" -- but I now believe you for the buttons (Foxtrott Uniform Charlie Kilo!) How do you boot into recovery/safe-mode then? There are not much other buttons you could "hold". Googling didn't trun up anything either. You might try to "play around": Reset and hold the "Power" key while it boots up, and the like.

Comment: I wasn't able to find the right combination of two positions of power button and reset hole and the timing of events. But when trying to find some information on archos web I have found firmware [here](http://update.archos.com/ht/archos7ht/rk_2818/UpdateA7HTv2.zip) and instructions [here](http://www.archos.com/support/support_tech/firmware.html?country=us&lang=en&g=6_4) which helped to solve the problem.

Comment: Wow. So a factory-reset can only be done via a firmware upgrade. And in case you're stuck in a boot-loop (and thus cannot connect it "as an external hard drive"), you're lost... ouch. But glad you've solved it! If you still feel you should be prepared for a possible "next time", it might be a good idea to contact their service and ask about this. If they come with good answers, next good idea would be to ask a "how to factory reset" question here and answer it yourself :)