# Problem with attaching Archos device on Ubuntu

Tags: adb

On my laptop I have Ubuntu 12.04.

1) mounting the tablet

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/tb
$ sudo chmod 777 /media/tb
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/tb
```

2) downloading and updating Android SDK

```
$ cd ~
$ wget http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130219.zip
$ cd ~/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130219/sdk/tools
$ ./android update sdk
```

3) editing rules for my device. [Each hardware device](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) has its ID. According to Archos
   website my vendor ID is `e79`. According to [this website](http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/archos-tablets/7079-connecting-archos-via-adb.html) I should also edit `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`.

```
$ sudo vim /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

After editing the file has this content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device",
ENV{PRODUCT}=="e79/*", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="e79", MODE="0666"

$ sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
$ sudo vim ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
```

after editing the file has this content:

```
0x0e79

$ sudo chmod a+r ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
```

4) updating the information

```
$ sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
$ cd ~/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130219/sdk/platform-tools
$ ./adb kill-server
$ ./adb start-server
$ sudo reboot
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/tb
$ cd ~/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130219/sdk/platform-tools
$ ./adb start-server
$ ./adb devices

List of devices attached
```

You can see that I have problem with attaching my device.

What else would you try to solve it?

Comment: Do you have *USB Debugging* enabled on your tablet? Most devices are not listed without that, as this setting starts the ADB service on the device.

Comment: @Izzy Probably no. I can't change anything in the tablet settings now (it's in the endless loop), I can only press the `force close` button.

Comment: Yepp, I remember. I was hoping you would remember if you had enabled it previously. In that case, I guess, you'll have to solve the other issue first (most likely via a factory-reset). Then check again with USB-Debugging enabled -- and report back if it worked out.

Comment: @Izzy USB Debugging solved it. You can write as the correct answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `adb devices` to list your device (and other ADB commands to be able to work with it), you need to enable *USB Debugging* in your Android device. This will start the required services (the ADB daemon) on the Android device, which is what then responds to ADB commands issued from your computer.

Besides: If you are not going to use all the development stuff from the SDK, but simply wnat to interact with your device using ADB commands, you don't need to install the entire SDK overhead. See [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) for details :)